# Get name of wrapped component from its higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

say my HOC is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

let validateURL = WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component{

    render() {
         if( wrappedcomponentnameis === 'xyz')
                 return ...
         elseif(wrappedcomponentnameis === 'abc')
                  return ...
         and so on....
    }
  };

export default validateURL;
```

how do I get the name of wrapped component inside this HOC?

Comment: Using `this.constructor.name`, OR - you could just return `this.props.children` in the `render()` method as an alternative.

Comment: `this.constructor.name` returns `_class2`, which is not the name of the component. `this.props.children` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via `WrappedComponent.name`:

```js
const HOC = WrappedComponent => class Wrapper extends React.Component{
  render() {
    if (WrappedComponent.name === 'Hello') {
      return <WrappedComponent name='World' />
    }
    
    return <WrappedComponent/>
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
  }
}
  
const App = HOC(Hello)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

However, I will prefer to pass optional props to the `HOC`, in order to control its behavior, because it's much safer, rather than relying on `WrappedComponent.name`.

For example: there are many libraries (as [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#withrouter), and etc) which provide some functionality to your components through HOC mechanism. When this libraries wraps your component, then `WrappedComponent.name` will point to the library HOC name and will break your logic silently.

Here's how you can pass custom props:

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponent, props) => class Wrapper extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const { shouldPassName } = props

    if (shouldPassName) {
      return <WrappedComponent name='World' />
    }

    return <WrappedComponent/>
  }
}

const App = HOC(Hello, { shouldPassName: true })
```

Comment: Hello, is there any way to get to the root component name, in case the component is wrapped/double wrapped in HOCs from libraries like React-Redux, React Router etc. Jest has something like .wrappedComponent that you can put in your tests to get to that. So I think that might be possible. Have to look a jest source code though for that .